# OpenCV not found when I have it installed?

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

I am trying to compile a cpp file from the dlib library using cmake.

When I use the command `cmake ..`

It gives me this error `OpenCV not found, so we won't build the webcam_face_pose_ex example.`

I have OpenCV installed and to be sure I just reinstalled it using `brew install opencv`

Would like some help on what else I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [opencv sources](https://opencv.org/releases/) and [follow the instructions](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#building-opencv-from-source-using-cmake-using-the-command-line) to build and install the project using make. This will allow make to install opencv to where it can find it later.

When complete, re-compile the dlib project using cmake.